# How can I print some SSRS reports via web application?

Tags: c#, vb.net, reporting-services, printing, ssrs-2008-r2

I am going to print some SSRS server reports from ASP.net application. the version of SSRS is 2008 R2 and visual studio is 2010.
I found a link for SQL server 2000 at [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bryanke/2004/02/11/printing-reports-programmatically-using-c-and-sql-server-2000-reporting-services/#code).
Anyone can help me how to improve that code to work with 2008 R2 please.

Many thanks, Emma

Comment: well, you just need to add report viewer to your application. It has built-in Printing function.

Comment: I don't need to view the report only want to print them. Should I use report viewer again?

Comment: solution references added

Comment: I can print the report now but get error when I am passing value to the parameters that has default value.

Comment: Then u need to pass in parameters before export and print
ReportParameter rp1 = new ReportParameter("ParaName",yourvalue);
            rep.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] {rp1});

Comment: In my code, I am using ParameterValue instead of ReportParameter and then render the ReportExecutionService by the parameters , is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

As Marco's comment goes, he's correct in the fact that Reporting Services in SQL Server do have options to "export" in various formats including PDF, excel, etc. but it is in the format that the report is built as

SQL Server 2008 R2 has Report Builder 3.0 (Google it, there are many resources and you can download and install) but in my case, I had these reports around for a few years and needed to keep in circulation. I embedded into an aspx page using Microsoft's ReportViewer Control (sample)

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Height="600px" 
    Width="100%" ProcessingMode="Remote" CssClass="reportStyle">
    <ServerReport ReportServerUrl="http://YourSQLServer/reportserver"
    DisplayName="Report Name" 
    reportpath="/<Your SQL Report Server Project Path>" />
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

but you have to do a lot of security configurations for your SQL Server to be able to connect so read up on the steps.
Here are some old references to creation of Reports.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/beginning-sql-server-2005-reporting-services-part-1/

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/beginning-sql-server-2005-reporting-services-part-2/

I had to use Visual Studio 2008 to create my original reports which I still use embedded in report pages...

HTH

Dave